# pairwise distinct left ends in all segments

Tags: algorithm

I am provided with M segments of form [L,R] of N elements of an array.I need to change these segments in such a way that all segments have pairwise distinct left ends.

Example : Let suppose we have 5 elements in array and we have 4 segments : [1,2],[1,3],[2,4] and [4,5] then after making all the left ends pairwise disjoint we have [1,2],[3,3],[2,4] and [4,5].Here all segments have different left ends

Comment: I don't understand your question. What are the allowed operations? How do you get to your example result?

Comment: @Nabla If there are two intervals [Li,Ri], [Lj,Rj] with same starting point Li=Lj and Ri<Rj then we may replace [Lj,Rj] with [L′j,R′j]=[Ri+1,Rj].

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if I got this.  I suggest

1. You sort all segments according to the right end.
2. Then you fix all the left ends, starting with the smallest right end working towards larger right ends. Fixing means you replace the current left end with the next available value.

In Python it looks like this:

```
def fit_intervals(datalist):
    d1 = sorted(datalist, key=lambda x : x[1])
    taken = set()
    def find_next_free(x):
        while x in taken:
            x = x + 1
        taken.add(x)
        return x

    for interval in d1:
        interval[0] = find_next_free( interval[0] )

data = [ [4,5], [1,9], [1,2], [1,3], [2,4] ]
fit_intervals(data)
print(data)
```

output: [[4, 5], [5, 9], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]

This function `find_next_free` currently uses a simple linear algorithm, if necessary this could certainly be improved.

Comment: What will be output here for these : [1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[4,5] and [1,2],[1,3],[3,4],[4,5]?

Comment: [1,2], [2,3], [3,4], [4,5] in both cases.  You can try this yourself here:  http://ideone.com/fKbmxw  , just press 'fork' above the source.